# Which one is grammatically correct: "one of the great" or "one of the greatest"?

Tags: grammaticality

I have been playing a [typing game](https://www.typingtest.com/test.html?minutes=1&textfile=aesop.txt) for a while now. The text starts with:

> Aesop was one of the great Greek writers...

Is "one of the great" grammatically correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Aesop was one of the great Greek writers...

and

> Aesop was one of the greatest Greek writers...

Are both grammatically correct and mean the same.

Comment: They're both grammatical and very similar in meaning, but "one of the greatest" may be slightly higher praise. Since being a great writer is a very vague concept, it's hard to be sure how many great or greatest writers there are (maybe there is a semi-official canon of great Greek writers, and if so then I've no idea how big it is). But for instance in "one of the good" vs "one of the best", or "one of the large" vs "one of the largest", you'd expect "best"/"largest" to refer to a smaller set than "good"/"large". It's impossible to quantify though.